# convergence of a power series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{3^\sqrt{n}}{n} x^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I have the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{3^\sqrt{n}}{n} x^n$.
The radius of convergence is 1 so there is pointwise convergence in $(-1,1)$.
Do I study also what happen in $x=-1,+1$?
The uniform convergence is in every compact $[a,b]\subset (-1,1)$?

Answer (score 1):

For $x \in \{-1, 1\}$, $\frac{3^\sqrt{n}}{n}$ doesn’t converge to $0$. Hence the power series can’t converge.

However a power series is normally convergent in all compact included in its disk of convergence. This provides a positive answer to your second question.

Comment: But why is the convergence uniform in compact sets $[a,b] \subset (-1,1)$? Does it come from a theorem or something?

Comment: If $\sum a_n x^n$ is a power series with convergence radius equal to $R>0$ and $0<A<R$, you have for $\vert x \vert \le A$, $\sum \vert a_n x^n\vert \le \sum \vert a_n \vert A^n$. Proving that $\sum a_n x^n$ is normally convergent on $\vert x \vert \le A$.